# Como cambiar la conexión en Eager Loading

Tags: php, laravel

Estos son mis modelos

```
class Posts extends Model {
    protected $connection = 'connection_1';

    public function comments()
    {
        $model = new Comments();
        $model->setConnection($this->connection);

        return $this->hasMany($model, 'comments_id');
    }

}

class Comments extends Model {
    protected $connection = 'connection_1';

    public function author()
    {
        $model = new Authors();
        $model->setConnection($this->connection);

        return $this->hasOne($model, 'id', 'authors_id');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        $model = new Posts();
        $model->setConnection($this->connection);

        return $this->hasOne($model, 'id', 'posts_id');
    }

}

class Authors extends Model {
    protected $connection = 'connection_1';

    public function comments()
    {
        $model = new Comments();
        $model->setConnection($this->connection);

        return $this->hasMany($model, 'authors_id');
    }

}
```

Cuando pongo estas líneas de código en mi controlador, el modelo Comments se conecta a connection_2 pero el modelo Authors está vació, imagino que no está cambiando la conexión a connection_2

```
$posts = new Posts;
$posts->setConnection('connection_2');
$posts->load("comments.author")->get();
```

Como puedo cambiar dinámicamente la conexión del modelo Authors, o porqué retorna vacío?

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo he resuelto así:

```
$conn   = \App\Helpers\Helper::connection($item_id);
$newPdo = \DB::connection($conn)->getPdo();
\DB::setPdo($newPdo);

$posts = \App\Posts::with("comments.author")->get();
```

Y en mi Helper:

```
public static function connection($project) {
    switch($project) {
        case 01:
            return 'connection_01';
        break;
        case 02:
            return 'connection_02';
        break;
        case 03:
            return 'connection_03';
        break;
    }
}
```